# how to integrate custom services into apache knox 0.9.1

Tags: knox-gateway

I got a need to integrate various service webUIs into knox gateway.For now ,i use CAS as authentication and got hdfs,hbaseUI,sparkHistoryUI worked fine.I searched google and baidu and found no detailed materials or docs for knox rewrite.xml,so i got problems in integrating new services such as kibana,hue etc.The root cause is that rewrite.xml contains many tags and attr that i just know nothing about.
As a try,i integrate tomcat7.0 ROOT webapp.here is the correspond service.xml and rewrite.xml:

[service.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pl3g.png)

[rewrite.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0a9LN.png)

when i connect the tomcat home page ,everything is ok.but when i clicked the hyper-link "configuration" in the navigation bar. i got infinite number of redirect and finally "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" in the browser.
My question is :1)how to write the rewrite.xml to make this demo work fine.
                2)is there any materials or documents about the detail of rewrite tags to share
I will appreciate if any one would help.thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with this article: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KNOX/Proxying+a+UI+using+Knox

For additional information, you can also see the documentation for service definition files: http://knox.apache.org/books/knox-0-9-1/dev-guide.html#Service+Definition+Files

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thank you! You helped a lot.I read the links you pasted above and the  article you wrote--"Adding a Service to Knox". With these knowledge in mind,i successfully integrated stormUI in knox in one hour.Appreciate your help again.

Comment: Finally, i am curious about that why knox doesn't integrate stormUI(supplied by storm ui server and http port determined by configuration ui.port) in built-in and just support  several REST API?

Comment: Glad to hear that you were able to make progress! The lack of StormUI support has only been based on demand. Please, please feel free to file a JIRA and post your service definition for it and we will incorporate it. I'm not sure what your "just support severeal REST API" comment means exactly. We support quite a few of the APIs for the Hadoop ecosystem by default and as you have seen provide a relatively straight forward means to contribute additional ones. I'd love to see you bring a discussion to the dev@ list for Apache Knox so the whole community can benefit. Thanks for your interest!